# HTML5 validation: field not required but, if filled in, must match pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, html, api, validation

Playing around with HTML5 validation, it occurs to me that it is (seemingly) not possible to validate the input of a field **unless** it is required.

In other words, it's not possible to say "this field is not required, but if you **do** fill it in, it must match pattern X." For example:

```
<textarea pattern='.{5,10}'></textarea>
```

With 1-4 characters (inclusive) entered into the textarea, running `element.willValidate` and `element.checkValidity()` both return true.

I know HTML5 validation isn't perfect just yet. Is the "validate only if it's filled in" concept not possible with HTML5?

Comment: Did you try including the empty pattern as well? `pattern='(|.{5,10})'>` Did not try it, just wondering :)

Comment: Good shout; I'll give it a go in the morning and see.

Comment: I gave it a go (win/ff30) and actually for me not having the required flag and defining a pattern worked as expected: `<input type="text" pattern="(a|b)"></textarea>` => accepting empty, `a` or `b` (http://jsfiddle.net/Armn6/)

Comment: Where do we submit a feature request for the internet? This would be very helpful.

Comment: on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

You can add another option in regex for completely empty text

```
<textarea pattern='(.{5,10}|^$)'></textarea>
```